# Invariant hyperplanes that does not pass through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $\alpha$ be an endomorphism of $V$. Under what circumstances does there exist a proper subspace $E<V$ and $\mathbf d\in V\backslash E$ such that the hyperplane $E+\mathbf d$ is invariant under $\alpha$?

I know that for some $2\times 2$ matrices, the invariant line does not pass through the origin. In general, if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $\alpha$, then there exists an invariant hyperplane which does not include $0$. However, having $1$ as one of the eigenvalues seem to be just a sufficient condition. Can anyone give a **necessary and sufficient** condition?

I am willing to limit the discussion to $V=\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$ if necessary.

Comment: You want a nonzero $d\in V\setminus E$, correct? Otherwise, $E+d=E$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes. Thanks.

Comment: Okay... I thought I had a proof, but it was wrong. Here's what I gleaned: Suppose such an $\alpha$, $E$ and $d$. Then $E$ must be an invariant subspace, and $T(d)-d$ must be an element in $E$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I think you are right. It seems that we have almost get there. Please feel free to write an answer when you have finished it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a linear transformation, $\alpha:V\to V$ and $d\neq 0$ and subspace $E$ such that $E+d$ is invariant.

We claim that $E$ must be invariant.

Indeed, if $\alpha(E+d)=E+d,$ then $d-\alpha(d)\in E\cap \alpha(E)$.

Therefore, if $v\in E\setminus T(E),$ then $v+d= v'+T(d)$ for some appropriate $v'\in T(E),$ but then $v=v'+T(d)-d\in T(E)$ by assumption, which is a contradiction. The other inclusion is similar, or you could simply say that $dim(E)\geq dim(T(E))$, but we just showed $E\subseteq T(E)$.

Now, we know that $\alpha(d)=d+w$ for some $w\in E$, so a necessary condition is the existence of an invariant subspace $E$ and a linearly independent one-dimensional subspace $E'$such that $\alpha(E')\subseteq E\oplus E'$.

In case $V$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C},$ apply the Jordan Normal Form to $\alpha$ restricted to $E\oplus E',$ yielding a basis of generalised eigenvectors. Note that one such generalised eigenvector $d'$must lie outside $E$ and hence $d'=\lambda d+w'$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ and $w'\in E$.

Then, $\alpha(d')=\lambda d+w+\alpha(w'),$ and $w+\alpha(w')\in E,$ implying that, in fact, $d'$ must be a generalised eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $1$.

As you seem to know that this is sufficient (which should also follow from the above), $\alpha$ has these properties if and only if one of its eigenvalues is $1$.

Comment: " in fact, d′ must be a generalised eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue 1." Why? Could you explain a bit here? Thank you.

Comment: $d'$ is a generalised eigenvector which is part of the basis observing the Jordan Normal Form of $\alpha$, so $\alpha(d')=kd'+v,$ where $v$ is some other generalised eigenvector. Since $d$ is linearly independent of $E$ the fact that the projection of $\alpha(d')$ onto $E'$ and $d'$ onto $E'$ are equal to $\lambda d$, implies that $k=1$.

Comment: Oh wait... I guess that's actually not quite right.

Comment: Okay. I randomly got it on a bus-ride: $E$ is itself invariant, so $E$ has a basis of generalised eigenvectors. Accordingly, there is a unique one-dimensional subspace of $E\oplus E'$ consisting of generalised eigenvectors with a non-zero $E'$-component. Combining this with the above *does* yield that $d'$ is a generalised eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $1$.